# How to search in Google map without using Google places API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I’m new to android. I have some doubt. How to search in Google map in android without using Google places API. Followings are my requirements.

1). I have a button called Gym in my App. When I click that button, then the nearest (for 5 kilo meters  surrounding from the current latitude and longitude) gym’s address should be listed with the details of kilo meters and travelling time, etc .

2). Then if I click any address from that list, then the Google map should be show the direction from current place to selected address.

How can I do this. Please some one help me.

Thanks,
Sathya.

Comment: If you need address alone you can do it using Geocoder. if you need any company organization or hospital name you need to use googleplaces.

Comment: for that you should use  both google places and map APIs